# How to placate a very angry priest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

So whilst going to rescue the Moth Priest 'Dexion Evicus', I think I accidentally might have hit him, not sure how. Anyhow the bearded maniac has taken this as a personal attack and refuses to accept a yield. Because he's so angry with me he'll just not quit, but being a quest NPC he can't die, nor can my companion Mjoll. So aside from the hilarious infinity battle, I thought, fair enough I'll talk to him whilst he's 'downed' and lo, I progressed the quest.

So I go back to the Dawnguard fortress, and he's there in the middle shouting murder and attacking everyone in the fortress! Clearly his rage knows no bounds.

[image]

Is there a way to forcibly pacify him without interring him? Or do I need to roll back and do over?

Comment: Opening the console, clicking on him, then typing `disable` then `enable` seems to have solved it.

Comment: You could try a Calm spell. I think that's what it's for. Not 100% sure as my modus operandi is 'kill first, don't ask questions later'

Comment: @Alex should make that an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening the console, clicking on him, so you see his ingame object id, then typing `disable` then `enable` seems to have solved it.

Using `setav aggression 0` didn't seem to have an affect.

Comment: Actually, setav aggression 0 is what prevented him from attacking you the second he was enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Although there is already an accepted answer, it relies on console commands, which are not available to console players (ironically).

You can try using a [Calm](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Calm_%28Skyrim%29) spell, which "reduces the target's inclination to attack for 30 seconds." However, the spell is level-dependent so you may not be able to use it on this particular NPC. You will of course also need access to the spell, through skill training or a scroll or staff.